# How to match two patterns in java?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, pattern-matching

i am able to extract data between two strings(sss & eee) using below code

e.g. of msg :
msg = "adg sss ,data1,data2,data3,eee";

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("sss(.*?)eee");
                
String  detect_start = null;

Matcher m = r.matcher(msg) ;
                 
                    while(m.find())
                    {
                        detect_start = m.group(1);
                    }
```

I get correct values in detect_start -> ,data1,data2,data3,

**Now i want to match two patterns**

**Pattern r = Pattern.compile("sss(.*?)eee");**

**Pattern ack_r = Pattern.compile("ack(.?)received");**

***How to do it ?***

I tried below line but it gives error that its not allowed

Matcher m = r.matcher(msg) || ack_r.matcher(msg) ;

I tried below logic but it **doesn't works**(only matches first pattern)

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("sss(.*?)eee");
 Pattern ack_r = Pattern.compile("ack(.?)received");                   
    String  detect_start = null;
  String detect_ack = null;
    Matcher m = r.matcher(msg) ;
Matcher m_ack = ack_r.matcher(msg);
                     
                        while(m.find())
                        {
                            detect_start = m.group(1);
                        }
                      while(m_ack.find());
{
         detect_ack = m_ack.group(1);
}
```

Comment: If you want to look for either one of those patterns you could combine them, e.g. `sss(.*?)eee|ack(.?)received` and then check whether you got group 1 or 2 (the other would be null). Alternatively, just use 2 matterhs like in your snippet - " it doesn't works" doesn't help though. You'd need to be more specific, e.g. what input, what expected output, what happened etc.

Comment: Also, please have a look at [ask] and note that a nicely formatted question is more likely to attract answers than close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a single regex alternation here:

```java
String msg = "adg sss,data1,data2,data3,eee ack blah blah received";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("sss(.*?)eee|ack(.*?)received");                   
Matcher m = r.matcher(msg);

while(m.find()) {
    String match = m.group(1) != null ? m.group(1) : m.group(2);
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

This prints:

```
,data1,data2,data3,
 blah blah
```